# jQuery toggle sort order and save to variable

Tags: jquery

I have the below code, which does work fine but I find it quite stupid and had hoped there was a cleaner "toggle" function or alike which I could use but it seems to be related to visibility only - and I want to set a variable (for later usage).

Can this below be optimized, if I want a toggle function which should be used to sort a column (and get the value in to a variable)?

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And the jQuery stuff:

```
var column;
var order;

$('thead th').click(function () {

  // Get the current column clicked
  var thisColumn = $(this).text();

  // Check if the column has changed
  if(thisColumn == column) {
    // column has not changed

    if(order == "ascending") {
      order = "descending";
    } else {
      order = "ascending";
    }
  } else {
    // column has changed

    column = thisColumn;
    order = "descending";
  }

  // Replace text in DIV
  $("div").text("column=["+column+"], order=["+order+"]");

  // future code will use the sort order to get database
  // stuff with Ajax

});
```

Check JSFiddle code here, http://jsfiddle.net/Psz5K/

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Instead of a global variable you can use data-attribute, order must be alphanumeric or a number 0/1 instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$(this).data('order', 'ascending')
```

Further it can be fetched using

```
var order= $(this).data('order');
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/xDY9d/)

I think this is better because you don't need any (potentially) global variables just to remember the elements. Just do another DOM query and you've got them

Comment: You didn't save the changes to your Fiddle demo as it is identical to mine.

Comment: Now you have changed the Fiddle demo but why do you think this is any better? It is the exact same - just with another variable declaration.